# WordPress 'Error establishing a database connection'

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am trying to start my 1st project in `WordPress` and put this data

1. `Database Name` : `wp-project-1`
2. `DB_USER` : `root`
3. `DB_PASSWORD` : ``
4. `DB_HOST` : `localhost`
5. `Table Prefix` : `wp_`

And in my `wp-config-sample.php`:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wp-project-1' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

But it says error like this when I submit them:

```
Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure the database server is running?
If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.
```

Here I am using `xampp` server, and my `xampp` port number is `3307` (I change that cause 3306 was busy every time.)

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on xampp you can open control panel where it says apache hit the config select php ini and find the following

```
mysqli.default_port=
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your `wp-config-sample.php` file to `wp-config.php`